# Matching text that is not html tags with regular expression

Tags: regex

So I am trying to create a regular expression that matches text inside different kinds of html tags. It should match the bold text in both of these cases:

```
<div class="username_container">
        <div class="popupmenu memberaction">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="username offline " href="http://URL/surfergal.html" title="Surfergal is offline"><strong><!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->**Surfergal**<!-- google_ad_section_end --></strong></a>
</div>



<div class="username_container">
        <span class="username guest"><b><a>**Advertisement**</a></b></span>
</div>
```

I have tried with the following regular expression without any result:

```
/<div class="username_container">.*?((?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)).*?<\/div>/is
```

This is my first time posting here on stackoverflow so if I am doing something incredibly stupid I can only apologize.

Comment: I think you should use a parser to handle this. It can take care of more cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/502381

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3978 ?

Comment: Well, I know that for this specific case regex are the wrong way do do it. But since this is a minor glitch that needs to be fixed when everything else is working I would prefer not to change technical solution and solve this simply by creating a little smarter regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse html is.. hard. See the links in the comments to your question.

What do you plan to do with these matches? Here's a quick jquery script that logs the results in the console:

```
var a = [];
$('strong, b').each(function(){
    a.push($(this).html());
});

console.log(a);
```

results:

```
["<!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->**Surfergal**<!-- google_ad_section_end -->", "<a>**Advertisement**</a>"] ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mk7xf/